# Audio tag html5

Tags: html, html5, css, javascript

Добрый, день! Имеется html конструкция.

```
< img src="/images/test"/ ><br/>
< p >Рандомный текст< /p ><br/>
< audio controls ><br/>
  < source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg" ><br/>
  < source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3" ><br/>
  Ваш браузер не пожжерживает тег audio!<br/>
< /audio ><br/>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы для браузеров, которые не поддерживают тег audio, вместо текущей конструкции выводилось 
одна ошибка "Ваш браузер устарел", вместо картинки-параграфа-ошибки"Ваш браузер не пожжерживает тег audio!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-audio-shiv-cssclasses-load)

вот пример с включенной проверкой на audio:

HTML

```
<div class="req_audio">
    <img src="/images/test" />
    <br/>
    <p>Рандомный текст</p>
    <br/>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        Ваш браузер не поддерживает ни audio ни javascript                
    </audio>
</div>
<div class="req_audio error">Ваш браузер устарел</div>
```

CSS

```
.req_audio {
    display: none;
}
.req_audio.error {
    display: block;
}

html.audio .req_audio {
    display: block;
}
html.audio .req_audio.error {
    display: none;
}
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/qu47a/)

js сгенерирован на сайте Modernizr

Comment: @eicto, спасибо, это то, что было нужно.